# Application of Convergence Dominated Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem. Determine $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx }$$

So, let $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx =\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx +\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx $$

So, I wanna apply the TCD to the integrals. We define $g_{n}(x)=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$, for $x\in[0,1]$ and $h_{n}(x)=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$, for $x\in[1,\infty)$. Therefore, $g_{n}\rightarrow 0$ and $h_{n}\rightarrow 1$ when $n\to\infty$. And, $|g_n|,|h_n|\leq x^n$. So by TCD,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx}=0\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx}=\int_{1}^{\infty}{dx}$$

So, the integral diverges. I don't know this is corerect. Anyway, I have other solution for this, if we use $u^{\frac{1}{n}}=x$, then

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}}dx=\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{u^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{(1+u^n)^{(\frac{1}{n}-1)+(2+\frac{1}{n})}}}dx=\dfrac{1}{n}\beta\left(\frac{1}{n}-1,2+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi\left(\frac{1}{n}-1\right))}$$
And this integral diverges. So, How can use the convergence dominated. Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong in your latter evaluation. 
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi(\tfrac{1}{n}-1)\right)} = -\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{n}\right)} \approx -\frac{\pi}{(\pi/n)} = -n$$ for large $n$.

Comment: How can the given integral be convergent to begin with? Both numerator and denominator have the same degree.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to see that the limit is $∞$, since
$$ ∫_0^N \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \ dx ≥ ∫_1^N \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \ dx ≥ ∫_1^N \frac{x^n}{x^n+x^n} \ dx ≥ ∫_1^N \frac{1}{2} \ dx = \frac{N-1}{2} → \infty$$

However I don't think you have applied the Dominated Convergence Theorem correctly, your dominating function needs to have finite integral. You seem to have bounded the functions by $x^n$ which does not satisfy this on the set $[1,∞)$.

The convergence of $g_n$ is true by DCT since $∫_0^1 x^n \ dx <∞ $ but does not help you answer the main question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You don't need the dominated convergence theorem. Just note that as long as $n>0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=1$, so for all such $n$ the integral is infinite (in fact, this shows that the dominated convergence theorem does not apply).